# Change Thousand seperator location in Excel using custom format

Tags: excel, formatting

I have local machine thousand separator setting as `00,00,00,000`. For just a single excel file, I want to change it to `000,000,000`

To achieve this, I am using this existing custom format.

```
[>=10000000]###\,###\,##0;[>=1000000]##\,###\,##0;##,##0
```

Now, the issue with this formatting is - It only works when the number of digits is less than `9`. if more than 9 it does not all any commas. Which makes this > `1234,567,981`

I tried using the custom format as

```
[>=1000000000000]###\,###\,###\,##0;[>=1000000000]###\,###\,##0;[>=1000000]##\,###\,##0;##,##0
```

Excel is not adding it. It gives an error. My best guess is there is a limit on a number of if that can be added to the custom format.

Any help is appreciated. I am open to using another method to achieve this.

Adding screenshot of Excel after implementing solution suggested in the answers below.

[image: Excel]

```
[>=10000000000]###\,###\,###\,##0;[>=1000000000]##\,###\,###\‌​,##0;##,##0
```

[image: Excel 2]

Comment: It gives an error. Which one?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
???,???
```

this works correctly for me up to 15 digits.

Comment: It works for you because your local setting will be to group 3 digits. My local setting is to group using 2 digits.